# cognitoUser.signOut() is not signing user out

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito User Pools, currently in their Beta stage, to handle my user accounts on my website.

In javascript i have the line:

```
cognitoUser.signOut();
```

Which should sign my user out, and I think set cognitoUser to null. After the above line I have the following code:

```
if (cognitoUser != null) {
     alert(cognitoUser.getUsername());
}
```

Much to my annoyance, this line is working, and popping up an alert with the should be signed out user's user name.

Why is the cognitoUser.signOut() line not working?? Do I have to sign the user out on the same page I signed them in on or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cognitoUser.signOut();
```

This function clears any locally cached tokens for that user. This function will not set cognitoUser to null. You would still be able to call all functions on this object, however those (such as getUser, changePassword etc) functions which require valid tokens will fail because the user has signed-out (i.e. no valid tokens).

Comment: is cognitoUser.signOut(); will make server call if call this code?